# Solve React/ Typescript error: Export variable is using name from external module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I use React with Redux and Typescript and get a strange error I do not know how to solve?

> Exported variable 'rootReducer' has or is using name
>   'ITransactionAddAction' from external module
>   "/Users/lony/Desktop/vest/react-stock-portfolio/src/store/account/types"
>   but cannot be named.ts(4023)

The named `ITransactionAddAction` is defined inside account/types which can be seen below and specifies the reducer for adding a transaction to the account storage.

rootReducer.ts

[image: rootReducer error]

store.ts

[image: store error]

I have two "redux stores" account and portfolio both are structured the same way having each one reducer and one types file.

To give an example here is the code of the account once:

account/types

```
// Data

export interface ITransaction {
  isin: string;
  order_action?: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
  cost: number;
  order_datetime: Date;
  valuta_datetime?: Date;
}

export type ITransactionArray = Array<ITransaction>;

export interface IAccount {
  transactions: ITransactionArray;
}

// Action

export const TRANSACTION_ADD = "TRANSACTION_ADD";
export const TRANSACTION_DELETE = "TRANSACTION_DELETE";
export const TRANSACTION_UPDATE = "TRANSACTION_UPDATE";

interface ITransactionAddAction {
  type: typeof TRANSACTION_ADD;
  payload: ITransaction;
}

interface ITransactionDeleteAction {
  type: typeof TRANSACTION_DELETE;
  payload: ITransaction;
}

interface ITransactionUpdateAction {
  type: typeof TRANSACTION_UPDATE;
  payload: ITransaction;
}

export type TransactionActionTypes =
  | ITransactionAddAction
  | ITransactionDeleteAction
  | ITransactionUpdateAction;
```

account/reducer

```
import {
  IAccount,
  TRANSACTION_ADD,
  TRANSACTION_DELETE,
  TRANSACTION_UPDATE,
  TransactionActionTypes,
} from "./types";

const initialState: IAccount = { transactions: [] };

const accountReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: TransactionActionTypes
): IAccount => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TRANSACTION_ADD:
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: state.transactions.concat(action.payload),
      };
    case TRANSACTION_DELETE:
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: state.transactions.filter(
          (item) => item.isin !== action.payload.isin
        ),
      };
    case TRANSACTION_UPDATE:
      const data = state.transactions.map((item) => {
        if (item.isin === action.payload.isin) {
          return action.payload;
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: data,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default accountReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern. Im not 100 % sure if this solved it, but I changed the following file and upgraded to React 16.13.1.

Please if you have the same problem, confirm if it worked or not?

**rootReducer.ts**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import accountReducer from "./account/reducer";
import portfolioReducer from "./portfolio/reducer";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  portfolio: portfolioReducer,
  account: accountReducer,
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

**store.ts**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer /* preloadedState, */,
  composeWithDevTools()
);
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare the type, for example:

in external lib has code like below:

```
interface privateProperty {
  name: string;
}
export const config = {
  propName: {} as privateProperty
}
```

in your code

```
// this config['propName'] contains non-exported type/interface
import { config } from 'external-lib';

// declare new type from private property
type Y = config['propName']; // or typeof config['propName']
// declare new type that extends Y
export interface X extends Y {}
// apply interface X which contains Private Type Name
export const yourVariable = {} as X;
```

done. now the problem fixed

result

before
[image: error]

after
[image: success]